# If I delete a game I downloaded, can I reinstall it later?

Tags: ps3, ps4, psn

If I remove a game on my PS4 to save space, will I always have that game, even if it is a PS+ title and can always install it again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will get to keep your games.  You'll notice that when you get the free PS+ titles, they're added to your account whether you download them or not.  Uninstalling games will not remove them from your library, which can be viewed at the far right of the PS4 home screen.

i.e. the library is tied to your PSN account, not the console's hard drive.

Please note that should you cancel your PS+ subscription at any point, any of the free monthly games you have in your account will be *removed* from your account until you re-subscribe to PS+.

Answer (score 5):

Normally, you can download any game you've downloaded before as often as you want to, free of any additional charge.

However, there is one exception to that rule: If the game has ever been pulled out for any reason, you won't be able to download it again until it somehow returns to the PSN. Luckily, the list of games that have been removed entirely is very short (the latest example would be P.T., which is a demo), and you can still use the game until you decide to delete it.

As for PS Plus games, they're treated like any other game. Just keep in mind that you won't be able to play those games without a valid PS Plus subscription. If it runs out, you only need to subscribe again in order to play.

Comment: I don't believe this has ever happened with paid content.  Note that there are many things that are no longer available for sale that can still be downloaded if you purchased them when they were.

Comment: Yes it has! It HAS happened with some paid games for PSP which had exploits allowing users installing them on Vitas and then running PSP homebrews made for the Custom Firmware (CFW) on PS Vita.

Answer (score 0):

PlayStation Plus titles are granted a special ownership status.

When you download a free PS+ title, without paying for it, you own it *as part of your PS+ status*. So, if you decide not to pay for PlayStation Plus anymore, then once it expires, you will not be allowed to play that game anymore. However, if you re-subscribe to PlayStation Plus, you will regain access. You don't even have to keep the game downloaded on your machine - redownloading it after resubscribing to PlayStation Plus works fine.

Source: I did this after I got my Vita and wanted to try some old games that were cross-play.